# Angular 4 upload photos (like Facebook does)

Tags: angular, file-upload, angular-reactive-forms

I am trying to copycat the way Facebook lets a user to upload photos in Angular using Reactive Forms.

Here is the html of the component:

```html
<form [formGroup]="houseForm" (ngSubmit)="submitForm()">
   <div class="form-group col-md-4">
     <label for="name">Name :</label>
     <input id="name" placeholder="Name" formControlName="name">
   </div>
   <div formArrayName="photos" *ngFor="let item of photos.controls;index as i ">

     <img [src]="url" alt="some text" style="width: 100px ; height: 100px;"/>
     <input type="file"  placeholder="photo ...." (change)="onFileChange($event , i)" >
   </div>


  <button type="submit" >Submit</button>
</form>
<button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="addPhoto()">Add Photo</button>
```

And my component code

```js
tempArray = [];
  url =  [];
  houseForm: FormGroup;
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.houseForm = this.fb.group({
      name: [''] ,
      photos: new FormArray([
        new FormControl()
      ])
    });
    }
    get photos(): FormArray { return <FormArray>this.houseForm.get('photos'); }

    addPhoto(): void {
    this.photos.push(new FormControl());
  }
  onFileChange(event , i) {
       const fileRead = new FileReader();
         if (!!this.tempArray[i]) {
             this.tempArray[i] = event.target.files[0].name;
             } else {
           this.tempArray.splice(i, 0, event.target.files[0].name);

         }
         fileRead.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]);
         fileRead.onload = (ev: any)=>{
           this.photos.patchValue([
             this.tempArray
           ]);
            this.url[i] = ev.target.result;
         };
         }
         
         
submitForm() {
     const formData = new FormData();
     formData.append('name' ,  this.houseForm.get('name').value);
     formData.append('photos' , this.houseForm.get('photos').value);
     setTimeout(() => {
       console.log('form classic ' + this.houseForm.get('photos').value );
      alert('done!');

    }, 1000);
  }
```

The problem is that only that once I select a file, all `<img>`s are showing that image so I need a way to preserve that photo as soon as I add another photo from the click.

Also I am using a temporary Array to upload a formControl, not sure if its the best way and to do it, and also that loop in the html not sure if its the best way.

Anyway I want to avoid using an input with multiple , since lots of users don't quite like to press Ctrl while selecting a photo.

Comment: i think  _fileRead.onload = (ev: any)=>{
           this.photos.patchValue([
             this.tempArray
           ])_ should be this.photos.push ?

Comment: not quite ... in a FormControl you can just patch a value or setValue , but that works ok .... actually I found the problem .... it was in my html my src attribute should have been url[i] not url .... I am so stupid :)))

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem; the problem was in my html `[src]` should have been `url[i]` not `url`.